# how to check how many html elements were checked

Tags: javascript

i need to find how many HTML elements were selected. my HTML file :

```
    <div>
      <label>kana </label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="kana" class="extra" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>kala </label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="kala" class="extra" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Ananas </label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="Ananas" class="extra" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Tomato </label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="Tomato" class="extra" />
    </div>
```

i came out with a solution that I need to do for loop to those elements and check if any elements were selected but it didn't work

```
    const extra = document.querySelectorAll(".extra");
    
    const myfunction = (extra) => {
      let count = 0
      console.log(toppings.value);
      for (let i = 0; i <= extra.length; i++) {
        if(extra[i].checked ===true){
          count++
        }
      }
    };
  myfunction(extra);
```

Answer (score 1):

1- Code has something incorrect so the function does not reach it's end at this line (console.log(toppings.value);) // toppings is not defined

2- Every time you want to count the elements check, you need to query them from the document (you are using a constant variable and getting it once no checked elements there)

3- In the loop (i <= extra.length) that makes i reaches extra.length which is unaccessible as the javascript array index is zero based, so you must have not used the equal operator

4- Function must return or display or even log the count of the checked elements.

**Working code**

```js
const myfunction = () => {
  let count = 0;
  let extra = document.querySelectorAll(".extra"); // (2)
  //console.log(toppings.value); (1)
  for (let i = 0; i < extra.length; i++) { // (3)
    if(extra[i].checked ===true){
      count++
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = count; // (4)
  return count; // (4)
};
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",myfunction)
```

```html
<div>
  <label>kana </label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="kana" class="extra" />
</div>
<div>
  <label>kala </label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="kala" class="extra" />
</div>
<div>
  <label>Ananas </label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="Ananas" class="extra" />
</div>
<div>
  <label>Tomato </label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="Tomato" class="extra" />
</div>
<button id="btn">Count</button>
<p id="result">0</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should tell to javascript Hey, there is a new change! when you check a checkbox
so you need to add an onChange on every checkbox
Also you need to give all checkbox on every function call when a change is occured

```
<div>
    <label>kana </label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="kana" class="extra" onchange="check()" />
</div>
<div>
    <label>kala </label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="kala" class="extra" onchange="check()" />
</div>
<div>
    <label>Ananas </label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="Ananas" class="extra" onchange="check()" />
</div>
<div>
    <label>Tomato </label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="Tomato" class="extra" onchange="check()" />
</div>
```

and js is:

```
function check(){
let counter=0;
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.extra')
checkboxes.forEach(element => {
    if(element.checked){
        counter += 1
    }
});
 console.log('counter is: ', counter);
}
```